# Error 1064 When trying to start tor service on windows 10

Tags: windows

What i have done:

1. Downloaded the tor expert bundle zip file
2. extracted the zip file to`C:\tor\`
3. Add the `C:\tor\Tor` to the `Path` system environment variable
4. Added `C:\tor\Tor\tor.exe` to the `LOCAL SERVICE` group with the `Full Control` privileges
5. Add `C:\tor\` directroy to the `SERVICE` group with the `Full Control` privileges
6. Created the `torrc` file in `C:\tor\Data\Tor\torrc`
7. Created the `C:\tor\Data\DataDir` directory
8. Used `tor --service install -options -f C:\tor\Data\Tor\torrc` to make tor service

The contents of the `torrc` file

```
DataDirectory C:\tor\Data\DatadDir
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:09...
```

What i get

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> tor --service install -options -f C:\tor\Data\Tor\torrc
Running on a Post-Win2K OS, so we'll assume that the LocalService account exists.
Done with CreateService.
Service installed successfully
Service failed to start : An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.
```

This is what i get when trying to manually start the service.

[image: error_1064]

I tried the `tor-win32` zip file from https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/7.5.1/ and the same error displayed again. Anyway when i run the command `tor --service install` the service is installed and started successfully. So i guess there is a problem with the `torrc` file.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: post your full `torrc` file, please - without passwords, cookies e.t.c... It's impossible to guess it all by the data you provided

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Hi, The question is asked 3 and a half years ago:). I'm a Linux user now and don't know even if the question is still relevant. Now that i'm here I recommend windows users to use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to run an executable as a windows service

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Actually, tor runs very well as a Windows service, so there should be no problem for the task you've tried to perform: windows 7,8 and 10 are running Tor service just fine out of the box

Comment: @pouya It's now over one year later and I can confirm this is still relevant. Getting the same issue, don't have a solution yet..

Comment: I fixed the same error by changing the relative path to absolute in torrc.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that none of the paths provided are relative or contain environment variables, because neither is handled properly. Also, I also had problems with paths because I used UNIX-style path separators on my Windows machine. `--verify-config` yelled at me what the paths provided were relative when they were not – because they explicitly started with the drive letter and root directory specification. I had to fix all of the above issues before the Tor service could run properly.